# $X$ normed, $l: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C}$ -linear and continuous then $\lVert Re(l) \rVert = \lVert l \rVert$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am studying Dirk Werner's functional analyis book, and have difficulties with the following (p. 96/97, Lemma III.1.3 (d))

Let $X$ be a normed space, $l: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}$ -linear and continuous then $\lVert Re(l) \rVert = \lVert l \rVert$.

They say it directly follows from this statement:

Let $p:X-> \mathbb{R}$ a seminorm, $l: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}$ -linear then it holds that
$\lvert l(x) \rvert \leq p(x) \forall x \in X \Leftrightarrow \lvert Re(l(x)) \rvert \leq p(x) \forall x \in X$.

To show that write $\lvert l(x) \rvert = \lambda*l(x)$ where $ \lvert \lambda \rvert = 1$. Then $\lvert l(x) \rvert = \lambda^{-1}*l(x) = l(\lambda^{-1}*x)= \lvert Re(l(\lambda^{-1}*x)) \rvert <= p(\lambda^{-1}*x) = p(x)$.

How I tried to solve the problem:

Does it hold that $\lvert Re(l(\lambda^{-1}*x)) \rvert = \lvert \lambda^{-1} \rvert * \lvert Re(l(x)) \rvert$, i don't think just because l is $\mathbb{C}$ - linear, $Re(l)$ is $\mathbb{C}$ - linear, is it?

Another idea: set $p(x) = \lVert l \rVert * \lVert x \rVert$.

Then (c) implies that $\lvert l(x) \rvert \leq \lVert l \rVert * \lVert x \rVert \Leftrightarrow \lvert Re(l(x)) \rvert \leq \lVert l \rVert * \lVert x \rVert$, but that doesn't really help me, does it?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it!
(I will assume $f=l$ in your question).

Setting
$p(x) = \lVert l \rVert \cdot \lVert x \rVert$
is a good idea.

Note that the righthand side of the equivalence
$\lvert l(x) \rvert \leq \lVert l \rVert \cdot \lVert x \rVert \Leftrightarrow \lvert Re(l(x)) \rvert \leq \lVert l \rVert \cdot \lVert x \rVert$
is always true.
thus, you know that the right-hand side has to be true.
This implies $\| Re(l) \|\leq \| l \|$.

For the other inequality,
define $p(x)=\|Re(l)\| \cdot \|x\|$
and procede similarly.

Comment: Yes, $f = l$, I'm sorry for the mistake. Now everything is clear, thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: (I think your first righthand side should be a left-hand side if I am not mistaken..)

Answer (score 1):

Since $|Re(l(x)| \le |l(x)|$, ($\Rightarrow$) is ok.

For ($\Rightarrow$), let $x \in X$ and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $|\lambda| = 1$ and $l(x) = |l(x)| \lambda$. Let $y = \lambda ^{-1}x$, then by linearity $l(y) = |l(x)| \in \mathbb{R}$ and by homogeneity $p(y) = |\lambda| p(x) = p(x)$. Since $|Re(l(y))|\le p(y)$, we have $|l(x)| \le p(x)$.

I hope that this answers to your question.

Comment: That was not really my question, I wanted to ask why $\lVert l \rVert = \lVert Re(l) \rVert$, which supinf already answered. But thanks for your effort.